# how to read PAC file using C++

Tags: c++, proxy, libcurl, pac

I am using libcurl for HTTP requests.

My application should be able to understand the proxy settings if the user has any

So it can be 
Proxy by proxy server or
Proxy by Auto proxy Configuration

I see support for PAC isnt available in libcurl

Since my application is in C++, are there any extension / parser engine available?

Thanks for reading the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PAC (Proxy Auto Config)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config#The_PAC_File) file is simply Javascript that has function `FindProxyForURL` returning proxy config string.

Technically, this function can use anything that Javascript can do, so you **must** bundle some Javascript engine to interpret it.

[**`tiny-js`**](http://code.google.com/p/tiny-js/) (simple single-file javascript interpreter written in C++) is the library that should fit the bill for this task.

**UPDATE**: [**`pacparser`**](http://code.google.com/p/pacparser/) library is pretty much ready-to-use engine designed specifically to parse pac files. Its downside that it bundles whole [`SpiderMonkey` Javascript engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey), which makes it rather heavy solution - it would add 1MB+ to your project binaries just to parse `pac` files.

If you can hack `pacparser` to use `tiny-js` instead of `SpiderMonkey`, that would be really nice solution.

Comment: any other libraries? :) pacparser has not-so-public license and tiny-js can only handle very simple codes

Comment: Can you provide an example of a library reading a PAC file? I can't find any examples on the internet....